# ensure nomenclature definitions are aligned

Tags: nomenclature

I have generated a nomenclature for my document and the horizontal spacing between the symbol and the definition stays constant no matter how long the symbol is. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
\begin{document}
Example of nomenclature 
\nomenclature{TIARLW}{This is a really long word}
\nomenclature{TOA}{This one also}
\nomenclature{a}{another}
\nomenclature{$\partial{u}/\partial{z}$}{Here's another one}
\printnomenclature
\end{document}
```

resulting in

[image]

How is it possible to make the nomenclature so that each of the definitions are aligned? Is it possible to treat this as a table?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can fix the `nomlabelwidth` (amount of space for symbols) by the optional argument to `\printnomenclature` like

```
\printnomenclature[<width>]
```

Initially it is fixed as `1cm`.

Full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
\begin{document}
Example of nomenclature
\nomenclature{TIARLW}{This is a really long word}
\nomenclature{TOA}{This one also}
\nomenclature{a}{another}
\nomenclature{$\partial{u}/\partial{z}$}{Here's another one}
\printnomenclature[1in]              %%% add width here.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Choose the appropriate value.